# Confusion regarding subinterfaces and superinterfaces

Tags: java, interface, subclass, implements

Given

```
public interface Subinterface extends Superinterface
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Implementor implements Subinterface
{
     ......
}
```

So my question is, **does `Implementor` have to define all the functions of 
`Superperinterface`** in addition to the **functions of `Subinterface` which it 
must define**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unless `Implementor` is `abstract`.